# Xcode 11.3.1 gives some Undefined symbol build errors

Tags: swift, xcode

Undefined symbol: *OBJC_CLASS*$_SKAdImpression
Undefined symbol: *OBJC_CLASS*$_SKOverlay
Undefined symbol: _SKStoreProductParameterAdNetworkSourceAppStoreIdentifier
Undefined symbol: _SKStoreProductParameterAdNetworkVersion
Undefined symbol: *OBJC_CLASS*$_SKOverlayAppConfiguration
Undefined symbol: *OBJC_CLASS*$_WKContentWorld

I am using Xcode 11.3.1 on Mojave. I guess it is too old for developing. Any workaround?

Answer (score 1):

You haven't given any details on how you got yourself into this situation. But yes, Xcode 11.3.1 is too old. The current version is Xcode 13.3.1, and you really can't do any useful work without it, because even if you got a project to compile and run, you could never do anything with it because it would be inadmissible for distribution.

So there's a sort of software/hardware chain of causality: you would need Xcode 13.3, so you need a *system* that can run Xcode 13.3, so you need a *computer* that can run that system, etc. That's the only "workaround": you have to participate in the never-ending treadmill of updates if you want to do Xcode development.